# How to reverse digits of each number in an array using pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I tried to write a program in C that reverses all the numbers in an array, but it actually doesn't reverse anything, so I get unchanged numbers back. I guess I got something wrong with the pointers.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse(int *n) { 
    int number = *n, number2 = 0;

    while (number!=0) {
        number2 *= 10;
        number2 += number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }

    *n = number2;
}

void ReverseDigits(int *p, int n) {
    int i = 0;

    while (i < n) {
        reverse(&p);
        p++;
        i++;
    }
}

int main() {
    int array[3] = {123, 456, 789}, i = 0;

    while (i < 3) {
        ReverseDigits(array, 3);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start with formatting this mess properly.

Comment: Next, enable all warnings and treat every single one of them as error!

Comment: `reverse(&p);` --> `reverse(p);`, `while (i < 3) {
        ReverseDigits(array, 3);
        i++;
    }` --> `ReverseDigits(array, 3);
    for(i=0; i < 3; ++i)
     printf("%d\n", array[i]);`

Comment: Why are you trying to reverse it 3 times?

Comment: Look at the `reverse()` function.  `number2` is computed as the sum of the digits of `*n` (aka `n[0]`) supplied to it.     Then `*n` is set to that value.    The logic has nothing to do with reversing anything.

Comment: @Peter: Actually the `reverse()` function correctly reverses the digits of the number pointed to by `n`, e.g. `123` becomes `321`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ReverseDigits` the variable `p` is an int pointer. When you do `&p` you'll get a pointer to int pointer. But your `reverse` function just expects an int pointer so your call of `reverse`is wrong. Simply do

```
reverse(p);  // insteand of reverse(&p)
```

In `main` you shall not call `ReverseDigits` in a loop as the function already loops the array (i.e. the number of elements passed). So skip the `while` and simply do:

```
int main() {
    int array[3] = {123, 456, 789};

    ReverseDigits(array, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your `reverse()` function is "both baffling, and necessarily wrong." *(Hey, don't take that personally...)*

How could such a function *possibly* work, without being told, not only *where* the (array) is, but how *long* it is? You seem to be missing a parameter here.

Once you've settled *that* problem in your design, the task of "reversing" an array is simply a process of "swapping" the first-and-last elements in an algorithm that goes something like this: *(pseudocode!)*

```
 function reverse( array[], array_size) {
   int i = 0;
   int j = array_size - 1;   // since zero-based
   while (i < j) {           // no need to use "<=" here"
      temp     = array[i];
      array[i] = array[j];
      array[j] = temp;
      i++;
      j--;
   }
 }
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the program is supposed to *reverse the digits* of each element in the array, i.e. `{123, 456, 789}` should become `{321, 654, 987}`.

Comment: An interesting possibility ... *(rolleyes)* ... leaving on-the-table the subsequent pondering: "so, exactly what does this have to do with 'an array?'"  Oh, well... I tried ... **:*)**